# Loading an assetbundle from the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I've created the ability to download and store an asset bundle to my device. Now I'm trying to load an assetbundle from an already downloaded bundle.

I'm saving the bundle like so:

```
IEnumerator Start ()
{
    WWW urlToLoad = new WWW(url);
    yield return urlToLoad;

    //read in JSON data
    string jsonContents = urlToLoad.text;
    var n = JSON.Parse(jsonContents);
    jsonURL = n["data"][0];
    Debug.Log(jsonURL.ToString());


    // split up the json and get last element in teh array
    string[] splitJSONURL = jsonURL.Split('/');
    string bundle = splitJSONURL[splitJSONURL.Length - 1];

    Debug.Log("array: " + bundle.ToString());

    //StartCoroutine(   DownloadAndCache());

    // save bundle to the application folder
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + bundle;
    Debug.Log("Path: " + path);
    SaveBytesAsFile(path, urlToLoad.bytes);
    savedBundleString = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + bundle;
}
```

Next I'm trying to load the bundle like this:

```
IEnumerator LoadLocalBundle(string filePath)
{
    print("Loading from local file..." + filePath);
    WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
    yield return www;

    if(www.error == null)
    {
        print ("loaded local bundle - instantiating :: " + www.assetBundle.mainAsset.name);
        GameObject bundleInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(www.assetBundle.mainAsset);
        assetBundle = www.assetBundle;

    }

}


void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Click"))
    {
        StartCoroutine( LoadLocalBundle(savedBundleString));
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, nothing loads.

What am I doing wrong?